# Proxy allocator with multiple specific allocators

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, allocator

For personal/academic purpose I'm working with custom allocators, specifically with pool allocators.

The next step I would take is having some class, each of which with its specific pool allocator, but each space request have to pass trough a proxy allocator that redirect to/call the right allocator for the class asking space.

The proxy allocator is in just to simulate statistical analysis, like number of allocation/deallocation for each class, and so on.

The call to the right allocator should be as transparent as possible to the user, so I would like something similar to:

```
ClassA* a = proxyAllocator().allocate();
ClassB* b = proxyAllocator().allocate();
```

and

```
ProxyAllocator::allocate(){
    /* sort of switch-case to call the right allocator */
}
```

It would be great if the whole process could be unaware a priori about the class I'll implement to get use of the allocators, like the allocator filling a map of class-allocator pair as the program run to be able to call the right allocator.

I've thought about the specific poolAllocator as a templated singleton, so it can be instantiated just one time for each class asking for allocations.

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: You might also find https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/wiki/BDE-Allocator-model interesting. This team has been pushing changes in the allocator model in the Standard Library. (Disclaimer: I work for the company, but not this team).